# change url with filter using checkbox and select

Tags: jquery, html

I create a filter system using a select and a checkbox with jquery, I want that when I click on one of the checkbox, the url changes with a parameter and when an option is selected in the select we add an extra parameter with a value, my problem is that when I choose one of the options the parameter in the url is not suitable as I want, here is the result that I want to get, and here is my code, thanks for your help.

code

```
$(':checkbox').on('change', function(){

  var path = '';
  var url = window.location.href;

     $(':checkbox').each(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            var checkedVals = $(':checked').map(function(){ return $(this).val(); }).get().join();
            window.history.pushState(null, null,'http://127.0.0.1/api/s.php?tags='+checkedVals);
        }

     });

});

$('select').on('change', function(){
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value');
    var currentUrl = window.location.href;
    window.history.pushState(null, null, currentUrl + '&type='+selected);
})
```

Here is a result that i want to get
[image]

Comment: set variable on on change event of both input. if that variable is set then you need to push parameter like this "&param=abc" else "?param=abc"

Comment: can you give an example please, thanks

Comment: yes I have mentioned it below

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
function pushState(){
         var path = '';
         var url = window.location.href;
         var checkedVals = '';
         $(':checkbox').each(function(){
           if(this.checked){
             checkedVals = $(':checked').map(function(){ return $(this).val(); }).get().join();
           }
         });

         var selected = $('select').find('option:selected').attr('value');
         window.history.pushState(null, null,'?tags='+checkedVals+ '&type='+selected);
    }
    $(':checkbox').on('change', function(){
        pushState();
    });

    $('select').on('change', function(){
        pushState();
    });
```

This will help you

Comment: one more thing is that on deselect of checkbox you have to set variable to false also for dropdown.

Comment: I try and when I chose the select, $ & type repeats several times on the url but that's what I want is that when the parameter is defined then we only change the value according to the select, an example on the codecanyon site as follows
https://codecanyon.net/tags/woocommerce,ecommerce?sort=price-desc

Comment: let me check it

Comment: @MaxDevs remove url from third argument you just need to pass what you want to append in your url.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(':checkbox').on('change', function(){
    pushState();
});

$('select').on('change', function(){
    pushState();
})

function pushState(){
     var path = '';
     var url = window.location.href;
     var checkedVals = '';
     $(':checkbox').each(function(){
       if(this.checked){
         checkedVals = $(':checked').map(function(){ return $(this).val(); }).get().join();
       }
     });

     var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value');
     window.history.pushState('', '','http://127.0.0.1/api/s.php?tags='+checkedVals+ '&type='+selected);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work :( here as an example that i want to get https://codecanyon.net/tags/woocommerce,ecommerce?sort=price-desc

Comment: what is the output you get from above solution?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: checkedVals is not defined
    at pushState (s.php:53)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (s.php:36)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)

Comment: Please check updated answer.. checkedVals is defined outside of each function.. now it should work..

Comment: @user3551009 nope the problem is third argument of history.pushState function. You are passing complete url which is not acceptable. You just need to add what you want to append.